# How do I wait for my thread factory to finish executing all its tasks?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, concurrency, managedthreadfactory

I'm using Spring 4.3.8.RELEASE with Java 7.  I want to create a thread factory to help manage certain workers in my application.  I declare my thread factory like so

```
<bean id="myprojectThreadFactory" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.CustomizableThreadFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="prefix-"/>
</bean>
<bean id="myprojectTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="threadFactory" ref="myprojectThreadFactory"/>
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="${myproject.core.thread.pool.size}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${myproject.max.thread.pool.size}" />
</bean>
```

However, I'm having trouble "join"ing on the threads.  That is, I want to wait for all work to be completed before continuing with a certain task so I have

```
    m_importEventsWorker.work();
    m_threadExecutor.shutdown();
    System.out.println("done.");
```

in which my thread pool is executed like so

```
public void work(final MyWorkUnit pmyprojectOrg)
{
    final List<MyWorkUnit> allOrgs = new ArrayList<MyWorkUnit>();
    if (pmyprojectOrg != null)
    {
        processData(pmyprojectOrg.getmyprojectOrgId());
    } else { 
        allOrgs.addAll(m_myprojectSvc.findAllWithNonEmptyTokens());
        // Cue up threads to execute
        for (final MyWorkUnit myprojectOrg : allOrgs)
        {
            m_threadExecutor.execute(new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    System.out.println("started.");
                    processData(myprojectOrg.getmyprojectOrgId());
                }
            }));
        }   // for
```

Yet what gets printed out is

```
done.
started.
started.
```

So clearly I'm not waiting.  What's the right way to wait for my threads to finish working?

Comment: what do you want to do with the threads ? are they working on the same dataset or separated datas ? Can you describe the flow ?

Comment: The threads are wokring on different data sets.  I would like to know when all the threads are done with their tasks, but evidently the "shutdown" mehod isn't the way to go.

Comment: You can call `m_threadExecutir.submit(...)`,and that method will return a `FutureTask` instance,you should call  `FutureTask`'s `get()` method which will wait for the task completed.

Comment: Do I have to invoke that for each potentially active therad?  For instance if I have 100 iterations of my loop do I have to call the "submit" method 100 times?

Comment: I'm too lazy to post this as answer, buy I think you are looking for awaitTermination method of executorService. This should be called right after shutdown. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm using Spring's ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, I found the below which suited my needs ...

```
protected void waitForThreadPool(final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolExecutor)
{
    threadPoolExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    threadPoolExecutor.shutdown();    
    try {
        threadPoolExecutor.getThreadPoolExecutor().awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}   // waitForThreadPool
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a fixed thread pool by using ExecutorService and check whether the pool size is empty or not:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
```

If you run your tasks by using this executor and check the thread pool size periodically by using @Scheduled fixedRate or fixedDelay, you can see if they are finished or not.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor poolInfo = (ThreadPoolExecutor) executor;
Integer activeTaskCount = poolInfo.getActiveCount();

if(activeTaskCount = 0) {
    //If it is 0, it means threads are waiting for tasks, they have no assigned tasks.
    //Do whatever you want here!
}
```

Comment: That will tell me at a fixed point in time if I'm finsihed, but I want to actually pause program execution until everything is completed.

Answer (score 0):

A `CountDownLatch` is initialized with a given count. This count is decremented by calls to the `countDown()` method. Threads waiting for this count to reach zero can call one of the `await()` methods. Calling `await()` blocks the thread until the count reaches zero.

You can use `CountDownLatch` to main thread to wait for completion all the task.You can declare `CountDownLatch` with size as number of task `CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);` in main thread call `await()` method to wait and every task completion call `countDown()`

```
public void work(final MyWorkUnit pmyprojectOrg)
{
    final List<MyWorkUnit> allOrgs = new ArrayList<MyWorkUnit>();
    if (pmyprojectOrg != null)
    {
        processData(pmyprojectOrg.getmyprojectOrgId());
    } else { 
        allOrgs.addAll(m_myprojectSvc.findAllWithNonEmptyTokens());

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(allOrgs.size());

        // Cue up threads to execute
        for (final MyWorkUnit myprojectOrg : allOrgs)
        {
            m_threadExecutor.execute(new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    System.out.println("started.");
                    processData(myprojectOrg.getmyprojectOrgId());
                   latch.countDown();
                }
            }));
        }  
       //After for loop
       latch.await();
```

Example:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);

Waiter      waiter      = new Waiter(latch);
Decrementer decrementer = new Decrementer(latch);

new Thread(waiter)     .start();
new Thread(decrementer).start();

public class Waiter implements Runnable{

    CountDownLatch latch = null;

    public Waiter(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Waiter Released");
    }
}
```

public class Decrementer implements Runnable {

```
CountDownLatch latch = null;

public Decrementer(CountDownLatch latch) {
    this.latch = latch;
}



 public void run() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            this.latch.countDown();

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            this.latch.countDown();

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            this.latch.countDown();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: THanks but I'm not clear how I would apply this to my question.  Are you saying when I create a Runnable instance I should create your "Waiter" class instead?

Comment: Create a countdown latch instance and pass to every runnable instance and do countdown. After calling work call await method

Comment: The "m_threadExecutor.shutdown();" was actually being invoked from a JUnit test, b/c in the test I wanted to check some conditions after the thrads were finished. I'd like to avoid adding code into my core project just to satisfy a JUnit test but if there is no other way to do this, I'll consider it.